# Grammar Trees in Neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, nltk

I'm trying to build a Grammar tree in Neo4j - are there trees already built using nodes and relationships?

I need to take an input string like this:

```
learn: context:english what is x outcome:describe(x) 
learn: context:<context> <sentence> outcome:<function> //generic syntax
```

and build nodes and edges like this

```
(what)-[:WORD_LINK]->(is)-[:WORD_LINK]->(x)->[:OUTCOME]->(describe(x))
```

Also, each `WORD_LINK` relationship, should have the attribute `context:english` in each word link.

Comment: I believe that it's easier to do with a parser generator (like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)) instead of Cypher.